# Call event receiver for many custom document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I have many custom document libraries. I would like to create and attach an event receiver for all these Library. With `<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">` they don't work.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you post your whole elements.xml here , bcoz <Receivers ListTemplateId="101"> is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically attach the event receivers to your document library as

```
list = web.TryGetList("ListName");

 if (list != null) {
    list.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "Namespace.ClassName");

    list.Update();
```

Or you can create a content type and attach event receiver to that content type and after that add that content type to your document library.